# ndis5.0 driver and Disable driver signature enfrcement

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, ndis

I was installing ndis 4.0 with 'disable driver signature enforcement'. and driver is giving no error and working fine. But same case for ndis5.0 driver is not working. 
Does ndis5.0 work with disabling driver signature enforcement. Or It must required signature.

Comment: For what it's worth: NDIS has nothing to do with signature enforcement.  Changing the NDIS version is unrelated to whatever the real problem is.

Comment: Why is this tagged 'linux'?

Answer (score 1):

NDIS version is independent of driver signature. Please recheck your code.